# How can I identify sandwich meats that have minimal nitrate/nitrite content?

Tags: meat, nutrient-composition

[The evidence seems fairly good to me that regularly eating food with high nitrite/nitrate content is carcinogenic](https://www.consumerreports.org/deli-meats/danger-at-the-deli-cold-cuts-increased-risk-cancer-heart-disease/), and I'd like to reduce the amount I eat in my diet. I'm finding it hard to identify sandwich meats (which I eat often) that I'm confident are low in nitrites/nitrates.

Many say "no nitrates or nitrites added", but Consumer Reports indicates that those likely have similar levels due to including them from natural sources like celery salt.

I've come across a variety of deli meats with various labeling, and I'd love if anyone can give insight on which are likely to be low in nitrates/nitrates. Here are a couple examples:

1. [Boar's Head Oven Roasted Turkey](https://www.safeway.com/shop/product-details.960242004.html?productId=960242004)

   1. "No preservatives" (Ingredients: Turkey Breast, Water, Less than 2%
      of Vinegar, Salt, Sodium Phosphate, Sugar)
   2. Is "No Preservatives" sufficient? Should I be concerned by the presence of salt or any other ingredient?
2. [Trader Joe's Smoked Turkey Breast](https://www.traderjoes.com/home/products/pdp/organic-hickory-smoked-turkey-breast-062667)

   1. "No nitrites or nitrates added | Except for those naturally occurring in sea salt" (Ingredients: Organic Turkey Breast, Water, Sea Salt)
   2. [Sea salt on its own seems to have trivial nitrate/nitrite content](https://www.thepigsite.com/articles/alternative-curing#:%7E:text=The%20authors%20found%20that%20the,is%20raw%20sugar%2Fturbinado%20sugar.), but are producers extracting it in bulk from sea salt?

Comment: You can of course make your own food choices but from the very source you linked at the papers linked therein there is *no* evidence directly linking the nitrite to cancer. The preventable cancer paper links a suboptimal diet in general with increased cancer risk and has 'too much processed meat' as one aspect of a suboptimal diet. It doesn't say anything about the nitrates. It is about the general low fat, low sugar, lots of fruit and vegetables makes an optimal diet and too much processed meat is a negative here.

Answer (score 1):

If you stay away from "cured" meats (ham, salami, anything unnaturally pink including most of the deli-mystery-meat products like bologna and olive loaf) and stick with things like turkey and roast beef that have not been steeped in a "cure" (code word for nitrates) you should be good-to-go.

Excessive salt/sodium content is normal in processed foods including deli meat, but that's different from nitrates/nitrites which you are asking about. Evidently you should look for and reject "uncured" products with celery in the ingredients.

Comment: From the Consumer Reports article: "There were 10 "cured" meats in our tests and 21 "uncured." On average, the nitrate and nitrite levels were essentially the same."

I don't think the cured vs uncured is a good heuristic here. I agree uncured with celery salt is a no-go, but the article doesn't provide any insight about uncured with sea salt. Do you have a source or citation to indicate that deli meats with just sea salt have minimal nitrate/nitrite content?